# How can I smoothly decrease a value if the player stops pressing LeftShift (GetKeyUp)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm just learning C# and you can tell that I am not very good at it, this is the main part of my current script that I need to work on:

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    speed = 10f;
    flySpeed = 6;
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    Camera.current.fieldOfView += 80 * Time.deltaTime;
}

if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    speed = 7f;
    flySpeed = 4;

    Camera.current.fieldOfView -= 250 * Time.deltaTime;
    Camera.current.fieldOfView = 100;
}

if (Camera.current.fieldOfView >= 110)
{
    Camera.current.fieldOfView = 110;
} 
else if (Camera.current.fieldOfView <= 100)
{
    Camera.current.fieldOfView = 100;
}
```

What I want to do is to increase the fieldOfView on my current camera when LeftShift is held down, and smoothly decrease the fieldOfView when LeftShift is released. I tried using this:

```cs
Camera.current.fieldOfView -= 250 * Time.deltaTime;
Camera.current.fieldOfView = 100;
```

but that just instantly changed the fieldOfView to 100 (walkingFoV)

Comment: It sets it to 100 because that's what you're telling it to do with `Camera.current.fieldOfView = 100;`. Is the line above it that uses delta not sufficient? If so, remove the line that sets it to 100. You may want to add a condition to stop the `-=` when your field gets to a certain value.

Comment: The line above it stops at 107.889 instead of 100 because of the fact that it only has a short amount of time to execute the command multiple times till it gets to 100, meaning it stops doing what I want it to (slowly decreasing the value till it hits 100) and just stops at 107.889. So because of that I thought I could make it just go to 100 right after it slowly decreases to 107.889 but I realized it would only execute Camera.current.fieldOfView -= 250 * Time.deltaTime; once meaning that it instantly goes to 100 FOV.

Comment: So no it's not sufficient

Comment: Sounds like `Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift)` triggers only once. You may want to add a variable that keeps track of state, maybe a boolean or a timestamp, and set this one when this KeyUp is triggered. Then don't set the FOV here but elsewhere. You can check the state somewhere else in this method, or a different method, to see if that state is set, and based on that apply your `-=` calculation. And don't forget to reset that state once you get to 100 FOV.

Comment: what's your porpose ? Is go left smoothly when keyup trigger ? if yes , you need setting a flag to keep run `Camera.current.fieldOfView -= 250 * Time.deltaTime;` because `Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift)` only trigger once, it can't keep going moving.

Comment: is there a max and min number for the FOV? also when decreasing the fieldOfView (when LeftShift is released) must it go back to the min?

Answer (score 1):

You want FOV to increase when button is pressed and decrease when it is not. Let's write that down:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    Camera.current.fieldOfView += 80 * Time.deltaTime;
else
    Camera.current.fieldOfView -= 250 * Time.deltaTime;
```

You might want to add your default logic here instead of capturing button press and release:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    Camera.current.fieldOfView += 80 * Time.deltaTime;
    speed = 10f;
    flySpeed = 6;
}
else
{
    Camera.current.fieldOfView -= 250 * Time.deltaTime;
    speed = 7f;
    flySpeed = 4;
}
```

In that case you have to write only one `if` instead of three, although both variants are perfectly valid.

And your last piece of code can be simplified to:

```
Camera.current.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(Camera.current.fieldOfView, 100, 110)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not smooth is because this code:

```
speed = 7f;
flySpeed = 4;
Camera.current.fieldOfView -= 250 * Time.deltaTime;
Camera.current.fieldOfView = 100;
```

All get's executed in the same frame (see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html).

In other words it only get's called once, so the camera's field of view instantly get's set to 100.

I wrote some code that should be able to replace your old code that should work the way you want it to. Another (possibly better) alternative is using Unity's Animation System by setting up animation for zooming the camera in and out and setting a trigger from script. (see https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/controlling-animation#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b4e3)

```
Coroutine zoom;
float timer = 0f;

public Camera main;
public float zoomedOutValue = 110f;
public float zoomedInValue = 100f;
public float zoomDuration = 0.2f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        if(zoom != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(zoom);
        }

        zoom = StartCoroutine(ZoomCamera());
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        if(zoom != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(zoom);
        }

        zoom = StartCoroutine(ZoomCamera(false));
    }
}

IEnumerator ZoomCamera(bool zoomIn = true)
{
    if(zoomIn)
    {
        while(timer < zoomDuration)
            {
                main.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(zoomedOutValue, zoomedInValue, timer/zoomDuration);
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                yield return null;
            }
        timer = zoomDuration;
        main.fieldOfView = zoomedInValue;
    }
    else
    {
        while(timer > 0f)
            {
                main.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(zoomedOutValue, zoomedInValue, timer/zoomDuration);
                timer -= Time.deltaTime;
                yield return null;
            }
        timer = 0;
        main.fieldOfView = zoomedOutValue;
    }
}
```